# Nginx write files into GridFS

Tags: mongodb, nginx, gridfs

We have the module "nginx-gridfs" (https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs) to serve contents OUT of GridFS, but are there any modules that can allow Nginx to accept upload files and write them into GridFS?

The Nginx upload module only supports uploaded files to be written on local file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should upload to GridFS using your web application that Nginx is serving. For example in Perl there's [MongoDB::GridFS](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB%3a%3aGridFS#put-fh-metadata).